# unable to connect laravel app with postgres

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, macos

i am trying to connect laravel app to azure postgres database the connection was working good but after the last update i get unknow error for me

Code

```
$connection = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$dbname user=$username password=$password") 
or die("Failed to create connection to database: MM<br/>");
print "Successfully created connection to database.<br/>";
```

result when connected to azure postgres database

```
php(16056,0x1e14b5300) malloc: double free for ptr 0x132862a00
php(16056,0x1e14b5300) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      php test.php
```

however with local connection the app working good

i try change php version

Comment: You should add some more details to have a relevant answer, but I would like to give you a general tip. Are you sure that the connection is working? Have you tried to create a simple php file (no laravel, no other framework/library) and test the connection string and pg_connect in isolation? Eg: `<?php $c = pg_connect("your plain connection string"); die("[{$c}] " . ($c?"Success":"Failure"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears there's a compatibility issue with the M2 Chip and PostgreSQL. This seems to be connected to OpenSSL, as a similar problem occurred today with another user, but in their case, it involved Python

[Malloc: double free error on M3 Macbook pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77577973/malloc-double-free-error-on-m3-macbook-pro)

"For the time being, consider setting 'sslmode' to 'disabled', at least until a fix is available. You can find more details about this setting in the PostgreSQL documentation here: [PostgreSQL - libpq - SSL Support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/libpq-ssl.html)."