# Malloc: double free error on M3 Macbook pro

Tags: python, django, memory-management, malloc, macbookpro

I am working on a Django python project with a postgres db hosted with render.com.

The code works fine on server and my imac. I recently got a Macbook Pro M3 (running sonoma). I have replicated the exact same setup and environment however when I try to run the code locally, I get

Python(40505,0x1704f7000) malloc: double free for ptr 0x1368be800
Python(40505,0x1704f7000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

The setup is the exact same on the other device and it works fine there. Here is the link to repo

https://github.com/moreshk/django-postgres

Any assistance would be useful.

Setup https://github.com/moreshk/django-postgres on my new device. Setup virtual environment, any dependencies and installed requirements and .env file. Would have expected it to run fine locally. Other Django Python projects seem to work fine, except this one which has a postgres db with render.com

When I try to run the code locally, I get the below error:

python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Python(40505,0x1704f7000) malloc: double free for ptr 0x1368be800
Python(40505,0x1704f7000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you have installed PostgreSQL with Homebrew,

`brew upgrade postgresql` and ensure you have version 14.10_1

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/155651#issuecomment-1827988313

```
psql(6636,0x10f1de600) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f916b00bc00: pointer being freed was not allocated
psql(6636,0x10f1de600) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc _error break to debug
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I experienced this same problem on an M2 Air, and upgrading `postgresql` also resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a long week chasing the issue. It fixed my celery and flask issues! For more information I'm working in a Intel Mac and happened the same, so probably the issue was not related to the architecture